# How can i query a where condition in Solr?

Tags: spring-mvc, solr, spring-data-solr

I need to write a solr query for search autocomplete where user can enter  a product_name  OR product_style_no where competitor_id=1 , and returns a list of competitors.
I ve used Spring Data Solr @Query annotation but not able to implement 'WHERE' condition in solr. Here is my code :

```
public interface ProductRepository extends SolrCrudRepository<Product, String>{

@Query("Product_Name:*?0* OR Product_Style_No:*?0*")
public Page<Product> findByProductNameORsku(String productName, Pageable pageable);

@Query("Page_Title:?0")
public Page<Product> findByPageTitle(String pageTitle, Pageable pageable);

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you do not want `competitor_id` to influence document score. I'd suggest usage of filter query.

```
    @Query(value="Product_Name:*?0* OR Product_Style_No:*?0*", filters={"competitor_id:1"})
    public Page<Product> findBy...
```

Once `competitor_id` probably  should not be hardcoded you can use a placehoder as well.

```
    @Query(value="Product_Name:*?0* OR Product_Style_No:*?0*", filters={"competitor_id:?1"})
    public Page<Product> findByPNameOrSjyFilterByCompetitor(String pname, int competitorId, Pageable pageable);
```